# Display "Test-NetConnection" Powershell command in Winforms TextBox

Tags: winforms, powershell

I'm trying to display the results of the Powershell command "Test-NetConnection" in a Winforms textbox.

```
        using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            ps.Commands.AddScript("Test-NetConnection");
            Collection<PSObject> result = ps.Invoke();
            foreach (var outputObject in result)
            {
                connectionStatus.Text += outputObject.ToString();
            }
        }
```

when I run "Test-NetConnection" in Powershell it works and if I switch out ps.Commands.AddScript("Test-NetConnection"); for ps.Commands.AddScript("ipconfig /all"); it works but for some reason using the "Test-NetConnection" command displays nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
 using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.Commands.AddScript("Test-NetConnection");
                Collection<PSObject> result = ps.Invoke();

                int i = 0;
                foreach (var outputObject in result)
                {
                    connectionStatus.Text += string.Format("===>Row N°{0} :\r\nComputerName : {1}\r\nRemoteAddress : {2}\r\nInterfaceAlias : {3}\r\nSourceAddress : {4}\r\nPingSucceeded:{5}\r\n",
                                                                i++,
                                                                outputObject.Properties["ComputerName"].Value,
                                                                outputObject.Properties["RemoteAddress"].Value,
                                                                outputObject.Properties["InterfaceAlias"].Value,
                                                                outputObject.Properties["SourceAddress"].Value,
                                                                outputObject.Properties["PingSucceeded"].Value
                                                            );


                       
                }
            }
```

Comment: your connectionStatus is a texbox? Have you set the property multiline to your textbox to true?

Comment: yes, I set multiline to true and it still doesn't work